# How to count a list of non primitive objects in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4.1

I need to count how many of an object there are and then store this number.

I have tried the following:

```
var order = db.Questions.Where(x => x.Owner == owner).Count();
```

which fails with the following message:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MVCApp.Models.Owner'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

I have modified the code to the following:

```
var order = db.Questions.Where(x => x.Owner == owner);
int bla = 0;
foreach (var item in order)
{
    bla++;
}
```

What I have done appears to work fine with no down side (other than needing an extra few lines of code), but, I would really like to understand this issue and the problem behind it.

The `Where` command is bringing the objects fine, so, why isn't the `Count` working?

Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: Please correct tags and question if you feel it is wrong... I am not certain if this is an Entity Framework issue or directly related to Linq queries :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that `owner` is an instance of a class, another entity, perhaps?.  In that case, what you probably want to do is check that the foreign key is the same as the owner id (or the reverse depending on how you have the relationship set up).  If this is true, the reason that it wasn't working before is that it doesn't know how to translate object equality into a SQL expression.  It needs to work with primitive types where the translation of the expression is defined.

```
var count = db.Questions.Where( x => x.OwnerID == owner.ID ).Count();
```

Comment: I am feeling a little bit of an idiot now - it appears that my foreach  loop isn't actually working as expected after all. I changed it to `x.owner.id == owner.id` - and now it does appear to work fine with the `count()`. ... I have to ask, is this a bug? The Single selection seems to work fine with complex types, and, considering this should just be a regular compare predicate, I can't really understand why it is more complicated... Anyway, many thanks for your answer. +1/Answer

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looping, I believe you should be able to do this:

```
var bla = db.Questions.Where(x => x.Owner == owner).AsEnumerable().Count();
```

I don't know why you wouldn't be able to get the `Count()` of items using EF but reverting to use LINQ to Objects here should work fine.

Comment: you would need to materialize all `Questions` for this approach - which would be very inefficient

Comment: Yes, unfortunate but at least it would be more effective than doing a loop.  Though it would seem tvanfosson's solution would be the better option.